# How to implement OPC UA LDS with Eclipse Milo?

Tags: kotlin, automation, opc-ua, opc, milo

I am currently working on a project that requires me to implement OPC UA LDS with Eclipse Milo and I had some questions.

1. What's the difference between a client connecting to a LDS and a non-discovery UA Server?
2. Since the UA Servers needs to connect to the LDS before calling registerServer() function, does the UA Server have to be given the URL of the LDS? If so, do you provide the UA Servers the discoveryURL of the LDS or the endpointURL of the LDS?
3. For a client to discover all the local UA Servers, does it first have to be given the discoveryURl of the LDS, then it needs to connect to the endpointURL of the LDS, then call findServers()?
4. What's the difference between the discoveryURL and the endpointURL?
5. Do all non-discovery UA Servers also have to contain findServers() and registerServer() function calls?
6. I am kind of confused on how to implement a LDS with Eclipse Milo since there is minimal documentation. I was thinking of first creating a dummy/bare-bone UA Server and then somehow adding in the Discovery Services but I am unsure of how to do it. Do you guys have any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between a client connecting to a LDS and a non-discovery UA Server?

Nothing other than perhaps intention. Connecting to an LDS you might expect to get multiple entries for other non-LDS servers when you call `FindServers`, but only one when connecting to a non-LDS server.

> Since the UA Servers needs to connect to the LDS before calling registerServer() function, does the UA Server have to be given the URL of the LDS? If so, do you provide the UA Servers the discoveryURL of the LDS or the endpointURL of the LDS?

Yes, it has to be configured with the URL of the LDS to register with, though the original intention for an LDS would be that it runs on localhost and has a canonical address of `opc.tcp://localhost:4840/UADiscovery` with a canonical endpoint URL of `opc.tcp://localhost:4840/UADiscovery/registration` for the endpoint that servers will use to register with.

I think the correct thing to do would be provide the server with the registration address, but it may not matter in practice.

> For a client to discover all the local UA Servers, does it first have to be given the discoveryURl of the LDS, then it needs to connect to the endpointURL of the LDS, then call findServers()?

Yes. In many cases the discovery URL and endpoint URL are the same, but if you're given a discovery URL that is different then you should use it.

> Do all non-discovery UA Servers also have to contain findServers() and registerServer() function calls?

`FindServers` should be implemented, `RegisterServer` and `RegisterServer2` are not required and should not be.

> I am kind of confused on how to implement a LDS with Eclipse Milo since there is minimal documentation. I was thinking of first creating a dummy/bare-bone UA Server and then somehow adding in the Discovery Services but I am unsure of how to do it. Do you guys have any ideas/suggestions?

Implementing an LDS is a non-trivial undertaking, made more difficult by the fact that LDS in general is under-documented in the spec because it's something that never really took off in the real world.

Unless you're just trying to learn about this OPC UA concept I think you may be wasting your time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It was insightful. One thing you mentioned is that "In many cases the discovery URL and endpoint URL are the same, but if you're given a discovery URL that is different then you should use it." Then why are there sometimes 2 URLs, one for discover and one for endpoint, if they can be the same? My understanding was that the discovery URL has no security and the client connects to that url to call findServers() to get the endpoint URLs of the UA Servers

Comment: Part 6 explicitly mentions that the Discovery Service Set may be at a different endpoint than the rest of the services: "Each OPC UA Server application implements the Discovery Service Set. If the OPC UA Server requires a different address for this Endpoint, it shall create the address by appending the path “/discovery” to its base address." So if you are given a "discovery URL" it is an endpoint _known_ to support the Discovery Service Set. That is all. Most servers use the same URL. I made the mistake in Milo of using separate URLs in some cases and I regret it.